# Extract rows based on two columns

Tags: r, extract

I have a data frame of bird-trapping data with two columns of interest: Set.Code and Status. The Set.Code is an alphanumeric value. Status is either a 1,2, or 3.

[image]

I need to ask R to extract all rows that have a Status of 2, AND all of the rows that have the same Set.Code as the row that has a Status of 2. So in the example above, I would be looking for the two first rows, since the first row has a Status of 2, and the second row has the same Set.Code as the row with a Status of 2.

I tried to extract all of the 2 Status, then get all of those set codes, and then extract all of those set codes from the dataframe:

Where my dataframe is data:

```
Captures <- data[data$Status==2,]

Codes <- unique(Captures$Set.Code)

data[data$Set.Code==Codes,]
```

but that did not work.

Comment: change the `==` in the last line to `%in%` should work?

Comment: Can you specify what sort of error did you encounter? I replicated your dataset and ran your code and it return me two rows with set.Codes "M1".

Answer (score 0):

You can use dplyr for this task where I copied the same framework you used until the last line where I stored the filtered observations into a new data.frame. (You can just have R show you the results too).

```
rm(list = ls())
options(scipen=999)
library("plyr")
library(dplyr)
```

Here I set-up up a sample data.frame.

```
num <- 1:4
char <- c("A","A","B","C")
ab <- data.frame(num,char)
```

Here is the Code I copied from you:

```
Captures <-ab[(ab$num==2),]
Codes <- unique(Captures$char)
```

Here is the dplyr used.

```
new.ab <- dplyr::filter(ab, num == 2 | char %in% Codes)
```

You should check out this guide for [more commands from the dplyr library.](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf)